# How to exclude in zedgraph one curve from auto-scaling the axes

Tags: zedgraph

How I can exclude in zedgraph one curve from auto-scaling the axes?  Example:  I have 3 curves in graph and want auto-scaling on X and Y axis only on first two curves but not on third one.  This third one will be visible only partially were it get into the range that sets by first two curves.
Thank you in advance
Ol

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an API to exclude a curve from the recalculation of the axis ranges, it considers all visible curves when AxisChange() gets called.

What you might be able to do is make the curve you want to exclude to be non-visible, call AxisChange(), then make the curve visible again.

```
    myCurveToExclude.IsVisible = false;
    zgc.AxisChange();
    myCurveToExclude.IsVisible = true;
```

It's a bit of a hack though, this could be problematic in the case where ZedGraph calls AxisChange() internally, but it might work for your purposes.